# How do I make a top jquery slider go from bottom to top?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I ran across this amazing slider but I would like to make it open from the bottom up, I have tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing seems to work for me. I changed the the box's (page container) css from having top to having bottom:0px and gave it a margin-bottom of -200. I managed to make it flip but it still opens from top to bottom.

Here is the demo file:
[slidingpanel.com](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/041_TopPanelWithJquery/demo/index.html)

I would appreciate some guidance.

Thank you
Sophie

Comment: If you remove the bouncing animation then it'd be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I made you this http://jsfiddle.net/wwZRQ/

This is with click : http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/V3q2w/

Give it a shot

Comment: OMG this is perfect! thank you thank you.. I guess this version is way easier. Ha! I am new to the whole javascript thing, so I have one more question: How do you make it appear onclick?  @moe